# Authorization header is not receiving in the backend Angular 2 + Spring Boot

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, cors, jwt

I am trying to pass the authorization header in the http request :

My Angular Code is like this:

```
 let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        headers.append('Authorization', this.uriRequest.appendAuthHeaderValue());
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

        console.log(JSON.stringify(options));

        this.http.post(this.urlManager.BASE_URL + this.urlManager.customerServiceURL, body, options).map(
            (response) => {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
            });
```

On the console i can found that in options my Authorization header is properly getting set :

```
{"method":null,"headers":{"Content-Type":["application/json"],"Authorization":["eyJhbGciOiJIUzIiJ9.eyJleHAiOjE1MDMyNTQ4NDIsInN1YiI6Ild25ldyIsInVzZXJJZCI6ImRlbW8iLCJyb2xlIjoiVFUiJ9.OvS69uweYIB96mQLt61RQVyoPnbY0aUhqpzUvHu40"]},"body":null,"url":null,"withCredentials":null,"responseType":null}
```

But in my backend i cannot able to get the token:

My COROS Filer:

```
HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
    HttpServletRequest  req = (HttpServletRequest) request;

res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS");
res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", " x-requested-with, Content-Type, Accept, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Language, Host, Referer, Connection, User-Agent, Authorization, sw-useragent, sw-version");
res.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Authorization");

    // Just REPLY OK if request method is OPTIONS for CORS (pre-flight)
    if ( req.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS") ) {
    res.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    return;
}
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
```

I am getting my token like this:

```
final String token = request.getHeader("Authorization");
```

Please help me on this i could not able to proceed from here.

Attached Screen:

OPTION:
[image]

POST:

[image]

RESPONSE Header:
[image]

[image]

Comment: In the Network pane of your browser devtools, what details do you see about the requests being sent (two requests: the CORS preflight OPTIONS request, and then the POST request)? What request headers does it show? What responses does it show? What are the response headers? What are the status codes for the responses? You should use  https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45784675/edit to edit/update your question and add all those details to the question. And what messages is the browser logging to the devtools console?

Comment: @sideshowbarker i have attached the screen from my browser network tab.

Comment: What you added doesn’t show the response headers. You want to especially show the response headers both for the first response—the response to the OPTIONS request. But anyway for now, that clearly shows your browser isn’t sending the Authorization request header in the POST request. That’s the reason your backend can’t access it right now—the Authorization is not actually there in the POST request that’s getting sent

Comment: @sideshowbarker sorry i have added those also.

Comment: OK so those headers all indicate that your browser is not seeing any Authorization request header coming from your frontend JavaScript code. Why that is, I can’t tell—but as far as your browser is concerned, there’s no Authorization request header there at all to begin with

Comment: @sideshowbarker I'm setting the authorization in the header and when I print the header it shows the authorization header is present then why it's not getting received at backed. I'm confused.

Comment: I’m not sure where you think you’re seeing it, but from looking at the headers you added from the your browser devtools, it’s very clear that the Authorization header is definitely not present in the request the browser is sending. And the value for the Access-Control-Request-Headers request header for the preflight OPTIONS request the browser is sending clearly indicates that the browser does not see any Authorization request header coming from your frontend code

Comment: @sideshowbarker yes you are right the in browser dev tools Authorization header is not visible. But, on my console i can see what all details are there in my header.

Comment: {"method":null,"headers":{"Content-Type":["application/json"],"Authorization":["eyJhbGciOiJIUzIiJ9.eyJleHAiOjE1MDMyNTQ4NDIsInN1YiI6Ild25ldyIsInVzZXJJZCI6ImRlbW8iLCJyb2xlIjoiVFUiJ9.OvS69uweYIB96mQLt61RQVyoPnbY0aUhqpzUvHu40"]},"body":null,"url":null,"withCredentials":null,"responseType":null}

Comment: @sideshowbarker finally I got my solutuon. Everything is fine except I was using ng2-slimbar-loader because of this issue was there because few customization I have done here to detect the rest calls and load the loader.

Answer (score 1):

If you still haven't found the answer. Here it is.

Headers in angular are immutable. So headers.append() actually returns a new header and the old one remains the same.

You have to use it like,

```
let headers = new Headers();
headers = headers.append("some-header", "value");
headers = headers.append("another-header", "another-value");
```

And then just pass this header.